# How to setup lxde tools with i3 in arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, lxde, i3

I am trying to maintain a minimal arch setup for which I want to have i3 but use some of the features available in lxde:

specifically:
 lxsession for lxpolkit
 lxapperance for gtk2 and gtk3 themes
 maybe stuff like windows switcher

lxpolkit only works when I run lxsession  so do I just autostart lxsession or is there a more elegant way around